# Using sns to plot a JIRA like created v/s resolved

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm struggling with a basic qs.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
q = pd.DataFrame(data=[[28,50,30],[29,40,40],[30,30,30]],columns=['sprint','created','resolved'])
```

I want to plot a barplot with sprint & for each sprint I want to plot created & resolved.

Can someone help out how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can use matplotlib in order to display information of pandas objects. In your case it seems for me the easiest way to go with pandas plots.
The following gives you a plot with only the information about the sprints as a bar plot

```
df.sprint.plot(kind='bar')
```

This gives you a plot for each sprint showing the created and resolved tasks

```
df.groupby('sprint').plot(y=['created','resolved'], kind='bar')
```